# Google Sheets, rename googlefinance headers

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas

I am using googlefinance to pull data from multiple tickers and I would like to differentiate by having different column names.

1. One solution I thought about is to rename the headers, I tried using nested query but it did not work.
2. Another (not very elegant) solution that I am thinking is to populate a row above with the ticker name, every 6 cells in a row, then concat the two rows.

You can see here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nDkIvVIWmibB2jiLyJCeHPNxdA11A1AMoavI-ICtSdE/edit?usp=sharing

What I tried and did not work:

```
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("C", "all", "02.01.2023", "20.12.2023", "weekly"), "SELECT newDate as Date", 1)
enter code here
```

and

```
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("C", "all", "02.01.2023", "20.12.2023", "weekly"), "SELECT * LABEL Date 'newDate'", 1)
```

The final outcome should be as example: USDCHF Date; USDCHF Open; .... APPL Date; AAPL Open; APPL Volume .... AMZN Date;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=reduce(torow(,1),tocol(A:A,1),lambda(a,c,hstack(a,let(Σ,googlefinance(c, "all", "02.01.2023", "20.12.2023", "weekly"),vstack(index(regexextract(c,":(.*)$")&" "&chooserows(Σ,1)),chooserows(Σ,sequence(rows(Σ)-1,1,2)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this kind of works but maybe I should have explained better the final outcoume which would be to have the headers named for each ticker differently. As such: AAPL Date; AAPL Close; AAPL Volume etc

Comment: Works perfectly now! The updated version.

Comment: I would like to add next a 7th column (for each ticker) that calculates the percentage change between previous day Close price. What is the best way to achieve that?